# Setting up Mono in Mac OSX

Tags: asp.net, macos, web-services, mono

I started using mac for my application developments. So, I wanted to host my asp.net webservices in my mac machine itself. My mac version is 10.8.5.
Following these 
http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/running-a-simple-asp-net-app-on-mac-os-x/
http://cushen.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/how-to-setting-up-mono-on-mac-os-x-part-one/

I installed the mono framework and executed the xsp command to start running the server. But my localhost was not up and running. So, I created a sample .cs file to check whether the installation was fine. But when I'm trying to run it through the terminal, I'm getting error - **The type or namespace name `system' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?**

Am I missing something here ? Please help

Comment: Probably you can start from a complete course, http://introcs.cs.luc.edu/html/, instead of shattered blog posts.

Comment: @Lex Li Thanks for the link. I went through this 
~~~
http://introcs.cs.luc.edu/html/monotools.html
~~~
and did the sanity check and is working fine.

To add some more details to my question : 
I have the web API developed and ready. I just want to make it up and running in my mac machine.

Comment: Then I suggest you start from OWIN self hosting. Unless Microsoft finishes ASP.NET vNext sooner, you will have compatibility issues running Web API projects on Mono/XSP.

Comment: Ohh ok, Thanks Lex...will try OWIN.....